# How to use Blackman Window in numpy to take a part of values from an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to take a part of values (say 500 values) of an array and perform some operation on it such as take sum of squares of those 500 values. and then proceed with the next 500 values of the same array.

How should I implement this? Would a blackman window be useful in this case or is another approach more suitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on several criteria:

1. Is the number of elements per operation an integer divisor of your array length?
2. Is the number of elements a significant fraction of your array length?

If 1. is True then you can reshape your array to use reduce-functions like `.sum(axis=axis)`, which is probably the most performant way. See @P. Camilleri answer for this case.

However if 1. is False then the second question becomes important. If you answer "yes" to 2. then you can just use a for-loop over the array because the Python loop overhead is not quite as significant for loops with few iterations:

```
width = 500
for i in range(0, arr.size, width):
    print(arr[i:i+width])  # do your operation here!
```

However if your answer is "No" to 1. and 2. you probably should use a convolution filter (see scipy.ndimage.filters) and then only pick the interesting elements:

```
width = 10
result = some_filter(arr)
# take only the elements starting by width_half and make "width" stepsize
result = result[(width-0.5)//2, :, width]
```

For example the sum of squares:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, (25))
arr_squared = arr ** 2

width = 10
for i in range(0, arr_squared.size, width):
    print(arr_squared[i:i+width].sum())
# 267, 329, 170
```

or using a convolution:

```
from scipy.ndimage import convolve

convolve(arr_squared, np.ones(width), mode='constant')[4::10]
# array([267, 329, 170])
```

Comment: for e.g i have 5000 elements in an array A. I used a 1-D window by taking 500 elements each. so resulting in 10 such windows! Is there a way I get the starting and ending indices of the 3rd window or any other specific window per say? Thank You

Comment: The values in the square brackets are the indices: `[i : i+width]` means take the values starting from index `i` until index `i+width` (last index not included). If you need those values you can just reuse the `for`-loop in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array a is 1D and its length is a multiple a 500, a simple `np.sum(a.reshape((-1, 500)) ** 2, axis=1)` would suffice. If you want a more complicated operation, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: and is there a way to get the starting and ending indices of the window after performing the square sum operation on it? so that I can go back and extract the 500 elements of the desired window!